# How to retrieve data using sqlalchemy from sqlite db in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, etl

I am not super skilled with python, and I have the following problem.
I am trying to make a python script where I download some data from Yahaoo finance, if there is no db already available create it, if there is, upload the rows that are not already available. (incremental process). For the moment, I am trying to retrieve data from db with a query.

The code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import logging
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, MetaData

class DataDownloader():
        
    def __init__(self, ASSET='TSLA'):
        self.ASSET = ASSET

    def download_and_save_data(self,interval='1d'):

        period = '10y'
        if interval[-1] == 'h':
            period = '719d'

        logging.info("Data download in progress")

        file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        data_folder = 'staging1_download'
        file_path = os.path.join(file_dir, data_folder, f'data_ASSET_{self.ASSET}_interval_{interval}.txt')
        
        
        data = yf.download(tickers=self.ASSET, period=period, interval=interval)
        data.sort_index(ascending=True)
        


        if interval[-1] == 'h':
            data = data.reset_index()
            data['Date'] = data['Datetime']
            data['Date'] = data['Date'].astype(str)
            data['Date'] = data['Date'].str[:-6]
            data = data.set_index('Date')
            cols_to_delete = [
                'Adj Close', 
                'Datetime',
                ]
        else:
            cols_to_delete = [
            'Adj Close', 
            ]
        data = data.drop(columns=cols_to_delete)

        #managing last available date. We want candles when markets has generated them.
        last_date_available = data.index[-1]
        current_date = datetime.now() 

        if interval[-1] == 'd':
            current_date = current_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
            if isinstance(last_date_available, str):
                last_date_available = datetime.strptime(last_date_available, '%Y-%m-%d')


        elif interval[-1] == 'h':
            current_date = current_date.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
            if isinstance(last_date_available, str):
                last_date_available = datetime.strptime(last_date_available, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        
        #logging.info(f"data downloder last date available {last_date_available} and current {current_date}")
        #logging.info(f"Cond verifiaction {str(current_date) == last_date_available}")

        if current_date == last_date_available:
            data = data[:-1]
        elif current_date < last_date_available:
            raise Exception("Something is wrong with dates during download. Please verify with data provider.")


        data.to_csv(file_path, header=True, index=True, sep=";")


        #when we switch to db
        
        file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        data_folder = 'staging1_download\\'
        database_path = os.path.join(file_dir, data_folder )
        databasePathName = database_path + 'staging1_download_DailyData.sqlite'
        print(databasePathName)

        #data["interval"] = interval
        data["Asset"] = self.ASSET
        data["INTERVAL"] = interval

        if not os.path.isfile(databasePathName):

            if interval[-1] == 'd':
                engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{databasePathName}', echo=True)
                data.to_sql("staging1_download_DailyData", con=engine, index=True)


        else:
            engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{databasePathName}', echo=True)
            query = f""" 
            SELECT * 
            FROM staging1_download_DailyData
            WHERE ASSET={self.ASSET} AND INTERVAL={interval}
            """
            
            df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
            print(df.shape)       
        

        
        logging.info("Data download executed")
```

The script should be runned two times. AT first will create the db correctly. At the second should print the df. But no df is printed. Instead it printed the following:

```
2024-02-16 23:48:27,522 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine PRAGMA main.table_info("
            SELECT *
            FROM staging1_download_DailyData
            WHERE ASSET=TSLA AND INTERVAL=1d
            ")
2024-02-16 23:48:27,524 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2024-02-16 23:48:27,526 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine PRAGMA temp.table_info("
            SELECT *
            FROM staging1_download_DailyData
            WHERE ASSET=TSLA AND INTERVAL=1d
            ")
2024-02-16 23:48:27,528 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2024-02-16 23:48:27,531 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine
            SELECT *
            FROM staging1_download_DailyData
            WHERE ASSET=TSLA AND INTERVAL=1d

2024-02-16 23:48:27,532 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2024-02-16 23:48:27,533 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
2024-02-16 23:26:44,201 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2024-02-16 23:26:44,208 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
```

what that means? no error is printed in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following modifications to ensure the select query works correctly:

- Instead of passing the `engine` directly to `pd.read_sql_query()`, I passed a connection object (`con`) created using `engine.connect()`.
- I used SQLAlchemy's `text` object by importing it with `from sqlalchemy import text` to create a SQL select statement.
- Using parameter placeholders in the `pd.read_sql_query()`, passed the parameter values `self.ASSET` and `interval`

Here's the modified code that resolved the issue:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{databasePathName}', echo=True)
con = engine.connect()
query = text(f""" 
SELECT * 
FROM staging1_download_DailyData
WHERE ASSET=:symbol AND INTERVAL=:interval_value
""")

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con, params={'symbol': self.ASSET, 'interval_value': interval})
print(df.shape)
```

Comment: "I enclosed [the (unsanitized) parameter values] in single quotes since they need to be treated as strings." - That is still vulnerable to SQL Injection, which is bad form. Better to use parameter placeholders and pass the parameter values via `pd.read_sql_query(…, params=…)`.

Comment: @GordThompson That makes sense. I updated my answer based on your suggestion. Thanks!